# How to filter an array of objects by month and year - Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, localdate

I'm new at Java and I have a question. I have this array of objects:

```
List<Expense> expenses = er.findAll();
```

That contains this:

[image]

I would like to know how can I filter this array by month and year.

A first example would be filter the array by month 10 and year 2021.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Seems like you are doing a DB call, any specific reason for not filtering it in query ?

Comment: Because I dont know how to do it using MongoDB, I tried many different ways to do it, but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Stream` API to do it as follows:

```
List<Expense> result = 
    expenses.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getDate().getMonthValue() ==  10 && e.getDate().getYear() ==  2021)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Alternatively,

```
List<Expense> result = 
    expenses.stream()
            .filter(e -> {
                LocalDate date = e.getDate();
                return date.getMonthValue()  ==  10 && date.getYear() ==  2021;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I recommend you do it in the second way to avoid `Expense#getDate` getting called twice in each step.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to @Avinds correct answer, I would suggest using `java.time.YearMonth` to make it obvious what is filterd:

```
YearMonth ymFilter = YearMonth.of(2021,10);

List<Expense> result = expenses.stream()
                               .filter(ex -> YearMonth.from(ex.getDate()).equals(ymFilter))
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: For most purposes this would be my preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for-each loop like in the following example.

```java
int monthNumb = 10;
for(expense ex : expenses) {
    if(ex.date == monthNumb) {
        /*behavior*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. This won’t work. (1) You can’t (safely) compare `LocalDate` objects with `==`. You need `.equals()`. (2) A `LocalDate` will never be equal to a month number, and certainly all the days in a month won’t be equal to the same month number. Please think again.